# How (if it is possible) can I get the version of Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How (if it is possible) can I get the version of Django REST framework?

```
import ?
print(?)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on what you need:

```
>>> import rest_framework
>>> print rest_framework.VERSION
'3.1.3'
```

Or:

```
$ pip freeze
...
djangorestframework==3.1.3
...
```

Answer (score 12):

if you have installed PIP, use below command

```
pip show djangorestframework
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have to install pip in the project then run this command and check the version

```
pip show djangorestframework
```

[image: enter link description here]

you can see in the picture

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use variable `__version__` or `VERSION` (check [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/__init__.py)):

```
>>> import rest_framework
>>> 
>>> rest_framework.__version__
'3.9.2'
>>> rest_framework.VERSION
'3.9.2'
```

In your shell you can use combination of pip and grep:

```
$ pip freeze | grep djangorestframework==
djangorestframework==3.9.2
```